# Upgrading database version automatically

Tags: android, android-sqlite, database-versioning

Hi i am creating an app which stores the password of the user entering. and whenever he needs to change his password then the data has to be changed.
The problem i am facing is while i am calling the DBHelper class (i created to do all my database works) its not deleting the table if it is available.

It will be more helpful if someone tells me how to delete the entries in the table while calling the DBHelper class.

I realized that the OnCreate and OnUpgrade functions are not executing except the first time while creating the database.

also changing database version automatically also helps i guess but i don't know how to do??
here is my code from DBhelper class

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DATABASE_TABLE+"'");
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE +" (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                KEY_ID +" INTEGER, "+
                KEY_X +" INTEGER,  "+
                KEY_Y +" INTEGER);"
                );  

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DATABASE_TABLE+"'");
        onCreate(db);
    }

public long createEntry(int name, int sx, int sy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ID, name);
        cv.put(KEY_X, sx);
        cv.put(KEY_Y, sy);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
```

Comment: Simply increasing the database version should do the trick. (know its late).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a row in the database should not affect the schema version. This should be executed as proper queries to manipulate the database entries.

You might find use of this method:

```
public void clearDatabase(Context context) {
   DatabaseHelper helper = new DBHelper(context);
   SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
   database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null); //erases everything in the table.
   database.close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was why the onUpgrade is not executing.

Answer (score 2):

**First** of all here is how you can change the database version programmatically and hence force the `SQLiteOpenHelper` to call `onUpgrade()` on the next call to open the database:

`db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version = " + NEW_VERSION);`

**Second**, I don't recommend using this technique. I only wrote this answer cause you asked about how to do it this way. It's your choice. **For me I'll do it the way @Boris Strandjev recommends in his answer**.